# Algorithm for grouping train trips

Tags: algorithm

> Imagine you have a full calendar year in front of you. On some days you take the train, potentially even a few times in a single day and each trip could be to a different location (I.E. The amount you pay for the ticket can be different for each trip).
>
> So you would have data that looked like this:
>
> ```
> Date: 2018-01-01, Amount: $5
> Date: 2018-01-01, Amount: $6
> Date: 2018-01-04, Amount: $2
> Date: 2018-01-06, Amount: $4
> ...
> ```
>
> Now you have to group this data into buckets. A bucket can span up to 31 consecutive days (no gaps) and cannot overlap another bucket.
>
> If a bucket has less than 32 train trips it will be blue. If it has 32 or more train trips in it, it will be red. The buckets will also get a value based on the sum of the ticket cost.
>
> After you group all the trips the blue buckets get thrown out. And the value of all the red buckets gets summed up, we will call this the prize.
>
> The goal, is to get the highest value for the prize.

This is the problem I have. I cant think of a good algorithm to do this. If anyone knows a good way to approach this I would like to hear it. Or if you know of anywhere else that can help with designing algorithms like this.

Comment: Sounds like a problem that can be solved with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Comment: I have a question, does the group of buckets have only consecutive days or it can have dates with a gap of more than 2 or 3 days.

Comment: So how would you create an artificial high prize, giving some reasonable restrictions, like max ticket price $10 and maximum 5 tickets per day? You would fill the first 31 days with 5 tickets each day and price $10. Then create the next bucket just thereafter, from Feb-1 to March-something. This would produce 11 red buckets of 341 days, leaving 14 or 15 days, but with 5*14, you would still fill a 12th bucket. But the real data isn't optimal. But you can try to fill a bucket from the first 31 days. If there aren't enough tickets, move the window 1 day forward, drop day 1, add day 32.

Comment: Move the window, until the first bucket is found. Then proceed the same way with the rest of the calendar. This should find a local optimum. But maybe, sacrificing the first day of the first bucket produces better combinations later? So you could try with delaying the first day, the first 2 days and so on, just up to 31 days, where you repeat the later intervals. But I fear you need to repeat the procedure for every bucket in your bucket-list-combination. Maybe you should start with a smaller intervall and less values (21 days, 3 days per bucket) to get some visualizable, testable datasample.

Comment: Maybe splitting the whole interval into 2 halfs and solving them separately, then trying to find a solution for the middle will help? On average, you need more than one ticket per day to fill a bucket.

Comment: Can `Date: 2018-01-01, Amount: $5` and `Date: 2018-01-01, Amount: $6` go to different buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by dynamic programming.

First, sort the records by date, and consider them in that order.
Let `day (1)`, `day (2)`, ..., `day (n)` be the days where the tickets were bought.
Let `cost (1)`, `cost (2)`, ..., `cost (n)` be the respective ticket costs.

Let `fun (k)` be the best prize if we consider only the first `k` records.
Our dynamic programming solution will calculate `fun (0)`, `fun (1)`, `fun (2)`, ..., `fun (n-1)`, `fun (n)`, using the previous values to calculate the next one.

**Base:**
`fun (0) = 0`.

**Transition:**
What is the optimal solution, `fun (k)`, if we consider only the first `k` records?
There are two possibilities: either the `k`-th record is dropped, then the solution is the same as `fun (k-1)`, or the `k`-th record is the last record of a bucket.
Let us then consider all possible buckets ending with the `k`-th record in a loop, as explained below.

Look at records `k`, `k-1`, `k-2`, ..., down to the very first record.
Let the current index be `i`.
If the records from `i` to `k` span more than `31` consecutive days, break from the loop.
Otherwise, if the number of records, `k-i+1`, is at least `32`, we can solve the subproblem `fun (i-1)` and then add the records from `i` to `k`, getting a prize of `cost (i) + cost (i+1) + ... + cost (k)`.
The value `fun (k)` is the maximum of these possibilities, along with the possibility to drop the `k`-th record.

**Answer:** it is just `fun (n)`, the case where we considered all the records.

---

In pseudocode:

```
fun[0] = 0
for k = 1, 2, ..., n:
    fun[k] = fun[k-1]
    cost_i_to_k = 0
    for i = k, k-1, ..., 1:
        if day[k] - day[i] > 31:
            break
        cost_i_to_k += cost[i]
        if k-i+1 >= 32:
            fun[k] = max (fun[k], fun[i-1] + cost_i_to_k)
return fun[n]
```

---

It is not clear whether we are allowed to split records on a single day into different buckets.
If the answer is no, we will have to enforce it by not considering buckets starting or ending between records in a single day.
Technically, it can be done by a couple of `if` statements.
Another way is to consider days instead of records: instead of tickets which have `day` and `cost`, we will work with days.
Each day will have `cost`, the total cost of tickets on that day, and `quantity`, the number of tickets.

---

**Edit:** as per comment, we indeed can not split any single day.
Then, after some preprocessing to get days records instead of tickets records, we can go as follows, in pseudocode:

```
fun[0] = 0
for k = 1, 2, ..., n:
    fun[k] = fun[k-1]
    cost_i_to_k = 0
    quantity_i_to_k = 0
    for i = k, k-1, ..., 1:
        if k-i+1 > 31:
            break
        cost_i_to_k += cost[i]
        quantity_i_to_k += quantity[i]
        if quantity_i_to_k >= 32:
            fun[k] = max (fun[k], fun[i-1] + cost_i_to_k)
return fun[n]
```

Here, `i` and `k` are numbers of days.
Note that we consider all possible days in the range: if there are no tickets for a particular day, we just use zeroes as its `cost` and `quantity` values.

---

**Edit2:**
The above allows us to calculate the maximum total prize, but what about the actual configuration of buckets which gets us there?
The general method will be backtracking: at position `k`, we will want to know how we got `fun (k)`, and transition to either `k-1` if the optimal way was to skip `k`-th record, or from `k` to `i-1` for such `i` that the equation `fun[k] = fun[i-1] + cost_i_to_k` holds.
We proceed until `i` goes down to zero.

One of the two usual implementation approaches is to store `par (k)`, a "parent", along with `fun (k)`, which encodes how exactly we got the maximum.
Say, if `par (k) = -1`, the optimal solution skips `k`-th record.
Otherwise, we store the optimal index `i` in `par (k)`, so that the optimal solution takes a bucket of records `i` to `k` inclusive.

The other approach is to store nothing extra.
Rather, we run a slight modification code which calculates `fun (k)`.
But instead of assigning things to `fun (k)`, we compare the right part of the assignment to the final value `fun (k)` we already got.
As soon as they are equal, we found the right transition.

---

In pseudocode, using the second approach, and days instead of individual records:

```
k = n
while k > 0:
    k = prev (k)

function prev (k):
    if fun[k] == fun[k-1]:
         return k-1
    cost_i_to_k = 0
    quantity_i_to_k = 0
    for i = k, k-1, ..., 1:
        if k-i+1 > 31:
            break
        cost_i_to_k += cost[i]
        quantity_i_to_k += quantity[i]
        if quantity_i_to_k >= 32:
            if fun[k] == fun[i-1] + cost_i_to_k:
                writeln ("bucket from $ to $: cost $, quantity $",
                    i, k, cost_i_to_k, quantity_i_to_k)
                return i-1
    assert (false, "can't happen")
```

Comment: its gonna take me some time to go over your suggestion. But to clarify, all tickets on a given day must be put into the same bucket. You will not be able to split them into two different buckets.

Comment: I made a fiddle with some data.https://jsfiddle.net/gttectt4/74/ However to double check that its correct, it would be nice to know what the day spans are that contribute to the total. IE the spans of the red buckets at the end. I'm barely following whats going on here... I though of a few ways to get the spans but everything I've tried gives me data that doesn't make sense. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @Curtis Added this part. About the fiddle, note `fun` is one longer than `cost`. My pseudocode uses `cost` from `1` to `n` and `fun` from `0` to `n`, all boundaries included. So I hope you pad the `cost` and `quantity` data with a single leading zero element when they are 0-indexed.

Comment: thanks for the help. I implemented your suggestion into a [new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6xszkL9/). Making sure to pad the costs and quantities with an extra 0 at the beginning. There was one notable change I had to make though... Your line: `assert (false, "can't happen")` needed to be replaced with `return k-1` and it seemed to work fine after that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Curtis Nice! I played with the fiddle, and looks like the place to fix is actually line 25: `k = fun.length;` to `k = fun.length - 1;` After that, the assertion works. Here, with one more line for debug output: https://jsfiddle.net/z6xszkL9/7/.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the challenge, but not too much, to make an overlookable example, which can be solved by hand.

That helps a lot in finding the right questions.

For example take only 10 days, and buckets of maximum length of 3:

[image: symbolic representation of tickets per day]

For building buckets and colorizing them, we need only the ticket count, here 0, 1, 2, 3.

On Average, we need more than one bucket per day, for example 2-0-2 is 4 tickets in 3 days. Or 1-1-3, 1-3, 1-3-1, 3-1-2, 1-2.

But We can only choose 2 red buckets: 2-0-2 and (1-1-3 or 1-3-3 or 3-1-2) since 1-2 in the end is only 3 tickets, but we need at least 4 (one more ticket than max day span per bucket).

But while 3-1-2 is obviously more tickets than 1-1-3 tickets, the value of less tickets might be higher.

The blue colored area is the less interesting one, because it doesn't feed itself, by ticket count.

Comment: this ignores the value of the tickets. If the ticket in square 4 is of a high value it would be more important to put that one in a red bucket. Also the rules are more complex than what you simplified it to. If you wanted a simpler version it would be... over 10 days, find the maximum sum of buckets (the prize) where each bucket is no more than 3 days AND has at least 4 rides (anything less than 4 would be blue). All buckets cannot over lap another bucket and must be continuous (no gaps in the days it spans).

Comment: Well, I thought that was implicitly clear, that you have to have at least n+1 tickets for for the max timespan (here 3, therefore 4) and therefore, day 4 (counting from 1) can't be in a red bucket. And of course without overlap and have to be continuous.

Comment: Sorry, you are right day 4 cant be in a red bucket. Its late (1AM) ill look at this again tomorrow. I need a rested brain.

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty ambitious problem. At least there aren't tickets of negative value. Beside from stealing a day from a later interval, where it might be more useful, there is no other reason not to take one more day in a greedy way.